# A one-point compactification of a non-separable metric space: separable or not?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, separable-spaces

I'm interested in compactifications of some non-separable metric spaces of functions.  For concreteness, consider $D[0,1]$, the space of right-continuous real-valued functions on $[0,1]$ with left limits, and give it the uniform (supremum) norm $\|f\|_\infty=\sup_t |f(t)|$.

The Alexandroff one-point compactification $D^*$ of $D[0,1]$ is compact, and $(D[0,1],\,\|\cdot\|_\infty)$ is a dense subspace of it. Is $D^*$ separable?

If it **isn't**, $D^*$ is a somewhat interesting example of a compact space that isn't separable ([this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785087/non-separable-compact-space))

If it **is**, $(D[0,1],\,\|\cdot\|_\infty)$ and $D^*$ are an interesting example of a non-separable subspace of a separable space ([this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/758424/give-an-example-of-a-non-separable-subspace-of-a-separable-space?rq=1))

But I have no idea which.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space $D^*$ is not separable, because otherwise $D[0,1]$ would be separable, being an open subspace of a separable space.